# incrementing a coredata detail view by swiping detail view

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've been trying to find an answer to this for a while.

I have a coredata table, when I select a entity from that table is pushes a detail view that has all the information in a detailviewcontroller.

I want the detailview to just refresh with the next objects details when swiped.  Has anyone seen a tutorial or example code for this function?

I've found this partial tutorial, but there are so many missing explanation of the parts I don't know where to start: http://craigcoded.com/2010/10/05/accessing-nsfetchedresultscontroller-results-on-the-detail-view-of-a-uitableview/

This looks like it should go in a tableViewController, not a detailViewController.

Thanks in advance.
Michael

It includes this decrement logic:

```
NSUInteger rowIndex = [[self storyIndex] row];
NSUInteger sectionIndex = [[self storyIndex] section];

if (rowIndex > 0) {
 rowIndex--;
} else if (sectionIndex > 0) {
sectionIndex--;
rowIndex = [[[[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:sectionIndex] objects] count] - 1;
}

storyIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:sectionIndex];

Story *story = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:storyIndex];
[self setupToolbarForStory:story];
[storyView setStory:story];
[storyView setNeedsDisplay];
```

and this increment logic:

```
NSUInteger rowIndex = [[self storyIndex] row];
NSUInteger sectionIndex = [[self storyIndex] section];

if (rowIndex < [[[[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:sectionIndex] objects] count] - 1) {
 rowIndex++;
} else if (sectionIndex < [[fetchedResultsController sections] count] - 1) {
 sectionIndex++;
 rowIndex = 0;
}

storyIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:sectionIndex];

Story *story = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:storyIndex];
[self setupToolbarForStory:story];
[storyView setStory:story];
[storyView setNeedsDisplay];
```